# Postman - Getting an error when manually POSTing

Tags: json, post, postman

I have a program that is sending http posts. Using Charles, I can see the raw data that is being sent:

```
POST /api/login/post HTTP/1.1
Host: *****.com
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 52
Accept-Language: en;q=1
Accept: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: ******/4.4 (iPhone Simulator; iOS 8.1; Scale/2.00)

{"password":"abc123","email":"*****@*****.com"}
```

I am bringing up the postman chrome extension and am trying to replicate the POST. For some reason, I get an error when I try and send the request:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Postman you are sending the body as `x-www-form-urlencoded`.  The request body is supposed to be application/json.

Not sure how you send a Postman request with a JSON body, but with [Runscope](http://www.runscope.com) it would look like [this](https://www.runscope.com/public/196bfc03-e52c-4bb2-932b-b466da7b363d/ea244c71-448a-491e-b776-17a078519c59)

Comment: @kinezu Does postman add the charset parameter?  It shouldn't be required but maybe the server is picky.  You could try doing it with Runscope, maybe that will behave slightly differently.

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you!

Comment: @kinezu  So, was it the charset?

Comment: It ended uo being the content type. It needed to be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"